# How to make a data collection instead of replace old data on firebase?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am a beginner and I am making a crud project to pratice and develop my skill. The app is a **Book list** app. Now I am trying to add the book to firebase when user add a book. But when I am doing that It is replacing the old data.

**Here is an image of firebase database:**

[image]

In my app users can create an account. Then they will able to make book list. So I want to add users book list under their id. But how to do that.

Here is my code.
Creating new data to firebase function is in the **submitHandler** function at line no 36.

**AddBook.jsx**

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import { addBook } from '../app/BooksSlice';
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from 'uuid';
import { auth, db } from '../firebase/firebase';
import { getAuth, createUserWithEmailAndPassword } from 'firebase/auth';
import {
  addDoc,
  collection,
  doc,
  serverTimestamp,
  setDoc,
} from 'firebase/firestore';

const AddBook = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState({});

  const inputHandler = event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const name = event.target.name;
    const value = event.target.value;
    setData({ ...data, [name]: value });
  };

  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const submitHandler = async event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const books = { id: uuidv4(), title: data.title, author: data.author };
    dispatch(addBook(books));

    // creating data to firebase
    try {
      await setDoc(doc(db, 'books', auth.currentUser.uid), {
        title: data.title,
        author: data.author,
        id: uuidv4(),
        time: serverTimestamp(),
      });
    } catch (error) {
      console.log('Got and error while adding new data to firebase', error);
    }

    // Navigating to homepage after successfull login
    navigate('/show-books', { replace: true });
  };

  return (
    <div className="container bg-dark py-3 px-5 mt-3 rounded">
      <form onSubmit={submitHandler}>
        <div className="form-floating my-3">
          <input
            name="title"
            type="text"
            className="form-control"
            placeholder="Title"
            value={data.title}
            onChange={event => inputHandler(event)}
            required
          />
          <label>Title</label>
        </div>
        <div className="form-floating my-3">
          <input
            name="author"
            type="text"
            className="form-control"
            placeholder="Author"
            value={data.author}
            onChange={event => inputHandler(event)}
            required
          />
          <label>Author</label>
        </div>
        <button className="btn btn-lg btn-light" type="submit">
          Add Book
        </button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};

export default AddBook;
```

Can you help me to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are currently saving the book with the ID of the user as document ID. This means, that the user can only have one book since the document IDs in a collection are unique.

This is shown in your code here:

```js
// you are using the auth.currentUser.uid as document ID
await setDoc(doc(db, 'books', auth.currentUser.uid), ...);
```

If you want a user to be able to own multiple books, then you could add documents with randomly generated IDs and the `userId` as field on the document. This will still allow you [to query data only for that user](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries?hl=en#simple_queries) and will also still allow you to write [security rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules/rules-and-auth?hl=en) so that other users can not read and/or write the books. Check out [this code snippet in the Firebase docs page, which uses the `addDoc` function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data?hl=en#add_a_document). In your example, it could look like this

```
// we add the userId to the document body, so that a user can have multiple books
await addDoc(collection(db, 'books'), {
     userId: auth.currentUser.uid
     title: data.title,
     author: data.author,
     time: serverTimestamp(),
});
```

*Please note, that the id field is also removed, since an ID will automatically be generated by Firestore.*

Comment: I'm glad, that I could help :)